# Setting up matrix-creator install and failling on "Unable to locate package matrix-creator-init"

Tags: matrix-creator

Following these instructions to test out the matrix-creator board.

Having issues with debian installation of the matrix-creator-init package

Any help?

https://github.com/matrix-io/matrix-creator-quickstart/wiki/getting-started

Answer (score 1):

Did you run the following command before trying to install the package?

echo "deb http://packages.matrix.one/matrix-creator/ ./" | sudo tee --append /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: thanks for the reply! yes I did. It for some reason didn't pull matrix-creator-init when I tried to install it. I'm going to try a fresh raspbian install

Comment: Good. Remember that you also need the "sudo apt-get update".